# Repacked proprietary software keeps updating the same deb

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, deb

I repacked a proprietary program delivered as tar file to a deb file for having a company wide repository.

I used reprepro to set up a repository and signed it. A unix timestamp is faking a versioning numbering, so I can have different (real) versions installed at the same time.
Almost everything works as expected. The deb file looks like this: mysoft8.0v6_1366455181_amd64.deb

Only problem on a client machine it tries to install the same deb file over and over again because it thinks its an update. What do I miss:

control file in deb package looks like this:

```
Package: mysoft8.0v6
Version: 1366455181
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: amd64
Installed-Size: 1272572 
Depends:
Maintainer: me
Description: mysoft 8.0v6 dpkg repackaging
```

and the config in the repository: /mirror/mycompany.inc/conf/distributions:

```
Origin: apt.mycompany.inc
Label: apt repository
Codename: precise
Architectures: amd64 i386
Components: main
Description: Mycompany debian/ubuntu package repo
SignWith: yes
Pull: precise
```

Help much appreciated

Added guide:
[This](http://blog.jonliv.es/2011/04/26/creating-your-own-signed-apt-repository-and-debian-packages/) Is the guide I used to create the repository.

Comment: A client side solution can be found here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package.

Comment: Ty for your input Jeffrey. I want to avoid configuring anything on the client for several reasons. We have a lot of workstations and if I have to configure a workaround for everyone I might as well skip the whole concept of a centralized software repository where I can push automatic updates to the users and install several versions in parallel. So this is not a real solution. On top I don't want to use a workaround for ill-configured servers. I must have made a mistake repacking the files and/or implementing the repository.

Comment: Using 'unix timestamp' may be the problem. Try a non-changing number

Comment: Prinz - The timestamp in the name is there for a fake versioning - since timestamp naturally always grow. This is done because I need to install several versions of the same software in parallel like this /opt/vendor/mysoft1 and /opt/vendor/mysoft2. If I repack I just create a new timestamp and I have a "newer" version without interfering with the real newer versions. But this is done in the packing process. Maybe the problem is not clear: The same package with the same name and version wants to update itself. I just mentioned the packing process, but I think it's a repository problem.

Comment: Would you be willing to post the lines from dpkg.log (/var/log/dpkg.log) that show the package being installed?  Maybe it will give someone a clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have different versions of the software installed at the same time, you need to use different package names rather than different version numbers; only one version of a package (identified by name) can be installed at the same time.

For example, let's say you need to have MySoft 7 and MySoft 8 installed at the same time, but also need to upgrade each version when the vendor releases minor updates. Maybe you start with MySoft 7.0 v6 which you want installed in `/opt/vendor/mysoft7` and MySoft 8.0 v2 which you want installed in `/opt/vendor/mysoft8` then you would build two packages:

```
Package: mysoft7
Version: 7.0.6
```

and

```
Package: mysoft8
Version: 8.0.2
```

to create `mysoft7_7.0.6_amd64.deb` and `mysoft8_8.0.2_amd64.deb`. In theory you can use whatever version scheme you want, but it would be advisable to conform to [Debian conventions](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) when specifying the version number.

Then, if you need to upgrade either version due to upstream changes from the vendor, then you would build a new version of the relevant package and update the relevant version number. For example, if MySoft 8.0 v3 is released, you would now build:

```
Package: mysoft8
Version: 8.0.3
```

Installing this package would then automatically uninstall `mysoft8` version 8.0.2 thereby removing the files installed from `mysoft8_8.0.2_amd64.deb` and replacing them with the files contained in `mysoft8_8.0.3_amd64.deb`

If you need every single upstream version installed at the same time, then you would need to use a different package name for every version. At this point, the package version number becomes irrelevant and you can just use `1.0`. Each would need to install to a different directory, because a file can only be owned by one package at a time. In this scenario, you would have to clean up unwanted old versions of the software manually by uninstalling the relevant package.

I am slightly unclear on why your current deb would try to reinstall if it is already installed (which, unfortunately, is the crux of your question!). It suggests that `apt` thinks that the version of the package available in your repo is higher than the version installed. Perhaps the size of the version number is confusing it? `/var/log/dpkg.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log` should show you what is going on.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your sorrow explanation. I believe I packed my packages as you described it. mysoft7.0v6 and mysoft7.0v7 etc ... 

The pseudo versioning is added to the normal versioning so my packages look like this: mysoft7.0v6_1366455181 and mysoft7.0v7_1366XXXXX etc...

Here is my history.log:
Start-Date: 2013-10-30 11:08:34
Commandline: apt-get upgrade.
Upgrade: mysoft7.0v6:amd64 (1366455181, 1366455181)
End-Date: 2013-10-30 11:08:53

Comment: Very odd. As an experiment, I would try rebuilding the package with a fixed, small version number instead of the timestamp. Then manually install on a client, wipe the old package from your repo completely (`reprepro remove precise mysoft7.0v6`?), import the new package into the repo and try `apt-get update` && `apt-get upgrade` again.

Comment: oops. sorrow = thorough :D. I'm not a native English speaker sorry. I think I will start all over as you have suggested.

Comment: used simple version numbering and update problem stops. Thank you.